# Python data to CSVs

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble getting my python data to write as csvs, either using pylab's rec2csv or using csv.writer.  I'm having particular trouble with rec.arrays that are of width 1 with rec2csv.  What I would like to do is have each element in an array (or list) as a column in a csv file.  For example, using any of these data types:

```
data = np.random.uniform(.5, .2, 1000)
data.tolist()
data = np.core.records.fromarrays(data)
```

It would also be quite helpful if I could change the name of the lat variable only.

Comment: Don't get the question but standard csv-module have everything you need, see http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with rec2csv or some of the other (numpy? scipy?) stuff you're using, but here is a simple example with the [standard csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("test_out.csv", 'wt'))
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = [n for n in xrange(len(l1))]
for row in xrange(len(l1)):
    writer.writerow([l1[row], l2[row]])
```